# Which government expenditures are paid for by income taxes?

Tags: taxes, budget

A publicly available listing of US government expenditures is available for download at https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/public-budget-database-outlays-and-offsetting-receipts-1962-current.  However, this lists all expenditures regardless of income source.  Some subfunctions are funded in part or whole by special taxes (such as the social security tax taken out of your paycheck separate from federal taxes), while the majority come straight from income taxes.

Is there an official source that denotes which subfunction codes are paid for by these special trusts instead of federal income taxes, or is it up to citizens to research each individual line item?

Comment: Don't forget, general coffers aren't just filled by income taxes. There are corporate taxes, payroll taxes, excise taxes, various fees, and at the state level there may be sales taxes as well. Income taxes is generally only about 40% of revenue. http://www.taxpolicycenter.org/briefing-book/background/numbers/revenue.cfm

Answer (score 4):

The reality is that all revenue goes into a general fund. All expenditures come from the general fund. Even Social Security is paid out of the general fund.

There are various trust funds but they are all accounting gimmicks with no relation to reality.

Comment: That's certainly true, but I was hoping to a breakdown of the official story for where the money is going.  So is there an authoritative source for these 'accounting gimmicks'?